# Laravel resource whenLoaded hasManyTrough relation

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to build a resource collection with a second resource based on a hasManyThrough relationship. When i call the actual relationship on the main resource it does provide me the correct data. Whenever i pass the data to another resource and use the whenLoaded() method, it doesn't chain the data to the main collection.

The model:

```
public function fields()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Field::class, FieldValue::class, 'component_id', 'id', 'id', 'field_id');
}
```

The controller:

```
/**
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function index()
{
    $components = Component::with(['fields'])->get();

    return ComponentValueResource::collection($components)->response();
}
```

ComponentValueResource class:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'fields' => FieldResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('fields')),
    ];
}
```

FieldResource class:

```
public function toArray($request)
{

    $fields = $this->whenLoaded('fields');
    return [
        'fields' => new ComponentValueResource($fields),
    ];
}
```

Output of `dd(FieldResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('fields')));`

```
#original: array:9 [
        "id" => 1
        "base_id" => 1
        "component_id" => null
        "identifier" => "text input"
        "type" => "text"
        "position" => 1
        "created_at" => "2021-08-22 19:44:23"
        "updated_at" => "2021-08-22 19:44:23"
        "laravel_through_key" => 6
      ]
```

Output from the resource:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 6,
        "fields": [
            []
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Is it possible to eager load the relationship in any other way to scaffold 2 relationships into 1 collection?